# How to add new skins to Agar.io

Tags: agar.io

I notice the Serbia's flag has been added to [this website](http://skinsagar.io/) but doesn't work on the game yet.

I would like to ask Agar.io to add Serbia's flag. Does anybody knows how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: @angussidney, the user is asking how to use a skin that they believe to already be in agar.io, and is not a custom.

Comment: @Timelord64 No, it's asking how to add a flag from a website to the game.  So, yeah, it's a dupe.

Comment: "But it doesnt work on the game, yet". Emphasis on the word yet, meaning OP thinks this will soon change. Also, the website linked is actually one of the best sources Ive found for skins, and presents them as a list of vanilla skins. They are simply incorrect in this instance

Answer (score 2):

Setting ones name to the corresponding skin is the only way to use alternate skins in vanilla agar.io.

There are several sites (including here at the Arqade) with lists of the available skins. However, due to how quickly this developer appears to modify the game, skins are often added or removed. For this reason, no source is 100% reliable, unless official.

It is possible that the website you source has a sneak peek at a future update the developer is going to publish. It is more likely they are showing a skin that is out-dated, or removed. It is also entirely possible that they have posted a "fake skin", as there are a lot of "fan art" skins floating around.

[The developer has a Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/user/Zeach), and appears to answer fan questions through this medium. You can ask there for a more reliable answer.